# MATLAB 2014b Parallel Figures

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, osx-yosemite, parfor

I am using MATLAB R2014b on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite. Since I will be plotting a large amount of figures, I am seeking for a parallel computing solution. The test code I am using is as follows:

```
    parfor ii=1:12
          figure(ii);plot(ii*2:ii:ii*10000);
          set(ii,'PaperPositionMode','auto','Color',[1 1 1]);
          set(ii,'Units','pixels','Position',[0 0 1200 800]);
          saveas(ii,[num2str(ii),'test.png']);
    end
```

MATLAB was able to generate the figures with the correct filename. However, the saved image is strangely cropped. An example of the images can be found here:
[image]

I tried removing the two lines which set the image size and paper position, however the problem still exists.

I would like to know what I have done wrong, or it is simply a bug with MATLAB R2014b.

Regards,
Jonathan

Update:

Just found out that such a problem does not exist with contour plots.

Comment: Your code is working properly on Win7 64 bit using MatlabR2014a. Do you have the cropping issue without `parfor` as well?

Comment: I have just tested without the parfor. It works just fine. It looks to me that the problem only occurs with parallel computer as going the SPMD route does not help at all. I am aiming to generate better quality image in parallel, which was forbidden in previous versions of MATLAB because of the OpenGL problem. Such an approach is only made possible as 2014b equips a better graphic rendering even without exporting with OpenGL.